# MySQL: Fetching non-null values using multiple joins

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

I am running a few queries which I want to convert to a single query using joins
My first query is

```
1)  SELECT * FROM ACT_TABLE1 where  node='5bbcdded' order by Instance_ID desc;
```

The output of the above query is as below

```
ID          Instance_ID NODE
2326600581  23266005612 5bbcdded1
2326524592  23265245712 5bbcdded2
2326523503  23265234213 5bbcdded3
2326523004  23265229614 5bbcdded4
```

2) Now, I grab topmost `Instance_ID` and run another select query as follows

```
SELECT * FROM ACT_TABLE2 where TOP_INST_ID = '23266005612';
```

Here, there might be a situation where `select query` returns a `null value` from above query. In that case, I grab second topmost `Instance_ID` and run same select query as follows

```
SELECT * FROM ACT_TABLE2 where TOP_INST_ID = '23265245712';
```

The output of the above query returns only single row as below

```
ID          NEXT_ID     TOP_INSTANCE_ID
232660056   232660056   232652457
```

3) Now, I grab topmost `NEXT_ID` and run another select query as follows

```
   SELECT * FROM ACT_TABLE3 where NEXT_ID = '232660056';
```

The output of the above query returns only single row as below

```
ID          EXEP_ID     NEXT_ID
232660072   232660139   232660056
```

4) Now, I grab topmost `EXEP_ID` and run another select query as follows

```
   SELECT field2 FROM ACT_TABLE4 where ID = '232660139';
```

The output of the above query returns `field2` which is my final result

In other words, I want to pass `node='5bbcdded'` in my `first table` so that i can fetch value of `field2` from my `fourth table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can do `Inner Join` between all the tables, using their relationships.
- Then, employ multiple level `Order By` clauses starting from the first table (all in Descending order, since you want topmost from all the tables). We use `LIMIT 1` to get the first row after sorting, which will be topmost.
- `Inner Join` will ensure that any non-matching rows (`null` in the next table) will be ignored.

Try:

```
SELECT t4.field2 
FROM ACT_TABLE1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN ACT_TABLE2 AS t2 ON t2.TOP_INST_ID = t1.Instance_ID
INNER JOIN ACT_TABLE3 AS t3 ON t3.NEXT_ID = t2.NEXT_ID 
INNER JOIN ACT_TABLE4 AS t4 ON t4.ID = t3.EXEP_ID 
where t1.node = '5bbcdded'
ORDER BY t1.Instance_ID DESC, t2.NEXT_ID DESC, t3.EXEP_ID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```